# open mpi not enough slots available

Tags: c, mpi, openmpi, hpc

I'm running a simple hello world program written in C on mpi and the problem I'm having is that i can't seem to execute 10 processes for this simple program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "mpi.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int rank; //rank of the process
    int size; //number of processes

    MPI_Init(&argc,&argv); //inititate MPI environment
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&size);

    printf("Hello world from process %d of %d\n",rank,size);
    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

i run it on terminal by:

```
mpicc -o hello helloworld.c
mpirun --oversubscribe -np 10 hello
```

Output:

```
Hello world from process 0 of 10
Hello world from process 2 of 10
Hello world from process 3 of 10
Hello world from process 9 of 10
Hello world from process 7 of 10
Hello world from process 1 of 10
Hello world from process 6 of 10
Hello world from process 5 of 10
Hello world from process 4 of 10
Hello world from process 8 of 10
----------------------------------------------------------------------- 
---
A system call failed during shared memory initialization that should
not have.  It is likely that your MPI job will now either abort or
experience performance degradation.
```

I realized the maximum i can go with oversubscribe on my dual core mac is 5 which doesn't generate the warning as above but anything more than that gives me the error and I'm not sure why.

Would appreciate some help on this. If so how do i reinstall open mpi?

Comment: This is something you should report directly at https://github.com/open-mpi/ompi/issues
Which version of Open MPI are you using ? How did you install it ? (pre-built binary ? `configure` command line ?)

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet I'm using the latest version of Open MPI 3.1.2. I followed the method here https://intothewave.wordpress.com/2011/12/27/install-open-mpi-on-mac-os-x/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Open MPI slots issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52534073/open-mpi-slots-issues) Do not ask the same question twice.

Comment: sounds like a race condition. meanwhile, you can `mpirun --mca shmem posix ...`

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet mpirun --mca shmem posix -np 10 hello in full?

Comment: you still need `--oversubscribe`

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet ok that worked but is there an alternative fix to it? Why does it happen without the commands you suggested?

Comment: `export OMPI_MCA_shmem=posix`. still sounds like a race condition to me.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet do i export OMPI_MCA_shmem=posix in terminal? Sorry I am really new to mpi. What does a race condition mean?

Comment: Did you try it before asking ? this is a shell script thing, not a MPI one. wikipedia and/or google will tell you more things about race condition I will ever know.

Answer (score 1):

This bug is tracked at https://github.com/open-mpi/ompi/issues/5798

Meanwhile, you can

```
mpirun --mca btl_vader_backing_directory /tmp ...
```

or

```
export OMPI_MCA_btl_vader_backing_directory=/tmp
mpirun ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem on mac even without oversubscribing the slots and the solution I first saw [here](https://github.com/open-mpi/ompi/issues/7393#issuecomment-882018321) worked for me. Try:

```
export TMPDIR=/tmp
```